# Postgres: Update a query counter once a result is returned

Tags: postgresql

I have a situation where a particular row can only be queried for a fixed number of times, say 1000. After which, it is made unavailable to that particular party permanently. Each query returns only 1 result i.e. LIMIT = 1.

I intend to implement this by having a counter that starts at 1000 and decrement with the number of times it gets queried.

Is there anyway where upon returning that result, that I am able to have its counter is immediately incremented?

This is as opposed to waiting for the result to be received by the application layer and then sending an UPDATE statement to increment the counter. Because between the time the result is returned till the time the UPDATE query is received, there can be another query.

Comment: Put the SELECT and UPDATE in a single transaction together.

Comment: but i don't know what to update before i select.

Comment: the idea is the update is done on the selected row.

Comment: Do a BEGIN TRANSACTION, do a SELECT, decide what to update, do an UPDATE, do a COMMIT.

Comment: I'm not familar with TRANSACTION syntax could you help me with it?

Comment: [BEGIN TRANSACTION](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-begin.html) is documented in the Postgres docs, like any other command.  See also the [discussion of isolation levels](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/transaction-iso.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CTE that does the SELECT and the UPDATE in one query:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(
    id int primary key,
    content text,
    counter int default 0);

INSERT INTO foo(id, content, counter) VALUES(1, 'foo', default);
INSERT INTO foo(id, content, counter) VALUES(2, 'bar', default);
INSERT INTO foo(id, content, counter) VALUES(3, 'baz', default);

-- select the data and update the counter:
    WITH    step_1 AS (
        SELECT * FROM foo WHERE counter < 5 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1 -- now you can use LIMIT as well
    ), step_2 AS (
        UPDATE foo SET counter = foo.counter + 1 FROM step_1 WHERE foo.id = step_1.id RETURNING foo.*
    )
    SELECT  * FROM step_2;
```

Comment: this seems like a brilliant idea.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately  you can not create SELECT triggers in PostgreSQL . but you can achieve this by Transactions

```
testdb=# BEGIN;
SELECT something FROM Some_table WHERE <where_criteria>;
UPDATE Some_table SET value = value - 1 WHERE <where_criteria>
COMMIT;
```

That where_criteria should be same for both statements

Comment: can i just ask when you begin the transaction, is the row that you selected being locked?

Comment: PostgreSQL didn't use locking mechanism it uses MVCC to achieve Isolation